# Draw a line after animation of each slice in a Donut - Chartistjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chartist.js

I am trying to draw a "tooltip" line on completion of each slice animation using [chartistjs](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/).

**Current situation**

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tech_boy/er401ac4/4/)

**Goal**

[image]

I am using chartistjs library to animate the donut. I am looking for drawing line on completion of each slice (svg animate) in the `chart.on('draw')` function.

Looking for a line after each slice. Any recommendations?

**Gist of code**

```
  var chart = new Chartist.Pie('#inner-donut', {
  series: [15, 20, 30, 25],
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}, {
  donut: true,
  showLabel: false,
  width: 800,
  total: 90,
  height: 400,
  chartPadding: 70,
  plugins: [
            Chartist.plugins.fillDonut({
                items: [{
                    content: '',
                    offsetY : -60,
                    offsetX: -200
                }, {
                    content: ''
                }]
            }),
        ]
});

chart.on('draw', function(data) {
  if(data.type === 'slice') {
    var pathLength = data.element._node.getTotalLength();

    data.element.attr({
      'stroke-dasharray': pathLength + 'px ' + pathLength + 'px'
    });

    var animationDefinition = {
      'stroke-dashoffset': {
        id: 'anim' + data.index,
        dur: 1000,
        from: -pathLength + 'px',
        to:  '0px',
        easing: Chartist.Svg.Easing.easeOutQuint,
        fill: 'freeze'
      },
    };

    if(data.index !== 0) {
      animationDefinition['stroke-dashoffset'].begin = 'anim' + (data.index - 1) + '.end';
    }

    data.element.attr({
      'stroke-dashoffset': -pathLength + 'px'
    });

    data.element.animate(animationDefinition, false);
  }
});
```

Comment: this is not enough code to post, no one will attempt to help you like this, kindly post a code that can reproduce the same result you post( the screenshot ).

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tech_boy/er401ac4/ But it doesn't seem to work.
P.S. I am new to jsfiddle, can you help me?  @AlaaMh

Comment: press **F12** and see the console it's telling that there is _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fillDonut' of undefined
    at window.onload_ it's a Javascript error I think solving it will make the fiddle work, check it out and try to solve it.

Comment: Thanks. solved and updated :) 
Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tech_boy/er401ac4/4/

Comment: once you update the url will change so you have to post the new one